# f x y = 3 + y/x in point free form

Tags: haskell, currying, pointfree

I'm trying to figure out the point free form of `f x y = 3 + y/x` in Haskell. I thought it would be `f = (3.0+) . flip (/)`, but the answer is `f2 = curry $ (3.0+) . (uncurry  $ flip (/))`, which is the same as `f1 = curry ((3.0+) . (uncurry (flip (/))))`, e.g. the answer I got but with uncurry before flip and curry at the beginning.

I see how that version works, but I'm not sure why the curry and uncurry functions are needed, and why my version doesn't work? The type of `(3.0+)` is `a -> a`, which I thought would work if you fed that function with the result form `flip (/)` via function composition, but `(3.0+) . flip (/) 2 10` results in an error (why?) and does not yield 8. Isn't it redundant to uncurry and then curry again?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type signature of the `.` is `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. As you can see, this only works if the **second** function (in your answer `flip (/)`) has **one argument**. In case it has two arguments, we can use the "owl operator" `(.) . (.)`, which has type:

```
(.) . (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> c
```

Or we can use currying. By using `uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c` on the `flip (/)` part, we construct a function:

```
uncurry (flip (/)) :: Fractional c => (c, c) -> c
```

so now we work with a *single* tuple (thus one argument), and then we use `curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c` to "unpack" the resulting first argument tuple again.

## Alternatives

As discussed before, we can use the *owl operator*:

```
   ((.) . (.)) (3.0+)  (flip (/))
-- ^   owl   ^
```

Or we can use a syntactically more complex version of the owl operator:

```
((3 +) .) . flip (/)
```